# XSLT obfuscation of nested information:

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to obfuscate the following xml, most of the work is already done, I obfuscated almost everything but the last nested data (the gender) I dont know how to deal with:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Report_Data
            xmlns:wd="urn:URN">
            <wd:Report_Entry>
                <wd:Candidate_ID>CANDID</wd:Candidate_ID>
                <wd:First_Name>FIRSTNAME</wd:First_Name>
                <wd:Last_Name>LASTNAME</wd:Last_Name>
                <wd:Email>EMAIL</wd:Email>
                <wd:Job_Requisition wd:Descriptor="JR0202517 Graduate Intern Technical (Open)">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">7f0219076bc1010a481ed02402b40000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Requisition_ID">JR0202517</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Requisition>
                <wd:Candidate_Stage1>REVIEW</wd:Candidate_Stage1>
                <wd:Candidate_Stage wd:Descriptor="Review">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">31350d72f899430fb446b410c1e368cd</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Recruiting_Stage_ID">REVIEW</wd:ID>
                </wd:Candidate_Stage>
                <wd:Created_Moment>2023-02-24T03:54:51.948-08:00</wd:Created_Moment>
                <wd:Job_Application_Date>2023-03-17</wd:Job_Application_Date>
                <wd:Job_Application_Source wd:Descriptor="Social Network -> Facebook">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dc8bf79476611087891d570080ae09fc</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Applicant_Source_ID">Facebook</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Application_Source>
                <wd:Phone_Number>PHONE</wd:Phone_Number>
                <wd:Country>COUNTRY</wd:Country>
                <wd:Internal>0</wd:Internal>
                <wd:gender wd:Descriptor="Male">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dc8bf79476611087d99a5866c88b70e2</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">M</wd:ID>
                </wd:gender>
                <wd:fileName>FILENAME</wd:fileName>
                <wd:attachmentContent>BASE64</wd:attachmentContent>
            </wd:Report_Entry>
        </wd:Report_Data>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I need the descriptor value "Male" and the value of gender code "M" to just go away without destroying the syntax of the whole request

Im using this xslt to obfuscate most values:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:Email">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Email]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:First_Name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Name]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:Last_Name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Last Name]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:Phone_Number">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Phone]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:attachmentContent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Base64 Attachment]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*:fileName">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated FileName]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

ive tried with the methods above to obfuscate both M and Male, but if I do them separately, due to copying from the template (I think) it just cancels the first changes.. Its my first day learning xslt and this is as far as I could go with this

Expected results:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:URN">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Candidate_ID>CANDID</wd:Candidate_ID>
            <wd:First_Name>[Obfuscated Name]</wd:First_Name>
            <wd:Last_Name>[Obfuscated Last Name]</wd:Last_Name>
            <wd:Email>[Obfuscated Email]</wd:Email>
            <wd:Job_Requisition wd:Descriptor="JR0202517 Graduate Intern Technical (Open)">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">7f0219076bc1010a481ed02402b40000</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Requisition_ID">JR0202517</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Requisition>
            <wd:Candidate_Stage1>REVIEW</wd:Candidate_Stage1>
            <wd:Candidate_Stage wd:Descriptor="Review">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">31350d72f899430fb446b410c1e368cd</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Recruiting_Stage_ID">REVIEW</wd:ID>
            </wd:Candidate_Stage>
            <wd:Created_Moment>2023-02-24T03:54:51.948-08:00</wd:Created_Moment>
            <wd:Job_Application_Date>2023-03-17</wd:Job_Application_Date>
            <wd:Job_Application_Source wd:Descriptor="Social Network -&gt; Facebook">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dc8bf79476611087891d570080ae09fc</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Applicant_Source_ID">Facebook</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Application_Source>
            <wd:Phone_Number>[Obfuscated Phone]</wd:Phone_Number>
            <wd:Country>COUNTRY</wd:Country>
            <wd:Internal>0</wd:Internal>
            <wd:gender wd:Descriptor="Obfuscated Gender">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dc8bf79476611087d99a5866c88b70e2</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">"Obfuscated Gender Code"</wd:ID>
            </wd:gender>
            <wd:fileName>[Obfuscated FileName]</wd:fileName>
            <wd:attachmentContent>[Obfuscated Base64 Attachment]</wd:attachmentContent>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
</env:Body>
```

</env:Envelope>

Comment: Please post your best attempt  so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Note that your statement that you need to make these two changes in a single template has no grounds.

Comment: Your xml is not valid since the namespace wd does not have a URI.

Comment: there, I uploaded everything I have until now @michael.hor257k

Comment: Please add also the expected result.

Comment: This makes no sense: `<wd:ID wd:type="OBfuscated Gender Code">M</wd:ID>`. Surely it should be `<wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">[Obfuscated Gender Code]</wd:ID>` ?

Comment: Yeah. you are right, im sorry its been a long day working with this and the clock isnt ticking as well as Id like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"` but the expressions that use a wildcard `*` as the namespace prefix require a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Now, I believe you could do quite simply :

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:URN">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Email">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Email]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:First_Name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Name]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Last_Name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Last Name]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Phone_Number">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Phone]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:attachmentContent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated Base64 Attachment]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:fileName">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>[Obfuscated FileName]</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:gender/@wd:Descriptor">
        <xsl:attribute name="wd:Descriptor">[Obfuscated Gender]</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:ID[@wd:type='Gender_Code']">
        <wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">[Obfuscated Gender Code]</wd:ID>
    </xsl:template>
       
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but (and im sorry, I know you are not here to teach people and I thank you for your time) what kind of magic was done on the last part? The gender code one i dont understand how it worked

Comment: I believe we are all here to learn... The last template matches a `wd:ID` element whose `@wd:type` attribute is `Gender_Code` and replaces it with the literal result  of `<wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">[Obfuscated Gender Code]</wd:ID>`. You could have achieved the same result using `<xsl:copy<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:text>[Obfuscated Gender Code]</xsl:text</xsl:copy>`.